# NPM install breaks with node version update

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am using NodeJS 16.13.0 and `npm install` works like it should.
But when I upgrade my NodeJS to either 18.x.x or 19.x.x, `npm install` breaks and a list of conflicts arise.

[image: ERESOLVE could not resolve]

The problem exists across multiple older projects with no matching libraries between them.
What is the logic behind this kind of problem. Everything works with NodeJS version X, but breaks with all newer versions Y.

And I am aware that `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` would fix that. I am looking for the root cause between NodeJS versions that causes this error.

NB! Using Ubuntu 22.04 but problem persisted in 20.04 as well

Thanks in advance,
Raidar

Answer (score -1):

remove npm from nodemodules and try to reinstall it again

Comment: That does not seem to be the cause